# How to add a public folder to react-boilerplate webpack config?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate

I'm setting up a new web app using react and its boilerplate the [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate). Now I want to add a public folder in the root that contains the index.html as well as the robot.txt .htaccess files and some external js libraries. Can someone please guide me through editing the webpack config files to make it behave like so.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin) to copy files from public folder to your build folder. Make the next steps to make it works:

1. Install [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin):

```
npm i copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

2. Edit your webpack.base.babel.js in /internals/webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'); <-- import plugin

module.exports = options => ({
    ...
    plugins: options.plugins.concat([
        ...
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([ <-- add plugin 
            {
                from: 'public',
            },
        ]),
  ]),
```

3. Now you can create folder `public` in your source root and all files from this folder will be copied to `build` folder.

IMPORTANT! You already have index.html which is generated from /app/index.html template by HtmlWebpackPlugin. If you created index.html in your `public` folder, it could override generated one.

Comment: Apparently, this is slightly outdated. This should work: `new CopyWebpackPlugin({patterns: [{from: 'public', }]})` from version *^11.0.0*.